# postgresql - customized output file with comma separated columns

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, psql

We are using postgresql 8/psql version 8.4. I am querying information_schema.columns for the column names and would like to generate a text file/output file so:

```
UNLOAD ('select 
col1,
col2,
col3,
col4,
col5)
to more text here
```

or

```
UNLOAD ( 'select col1,col2,col3,col4,col5) to more text here
```

So, I'm basically looking to output the **`colname`** followed by a `","` - `colname,`

Is this possible? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will create a string like that:

```
SELECT  'UNLOAD ( ''select ' ||
        array_to_string(array_agg(column_name::text), ',') ||
        ' to more text here'
FROM    information_schema.columns
WHERE   table_schema = 'public'
AND     table_name = 'whatever'
;
```

You can use `\o` to send it to a file, or use `COPY (...) TO STDOUT`.

Comment: another thing. what if I need to add a quoted string? `' to more 'text' here'`

Comment: If you put two single quotes next to each other inside a single-quoted string, that will give you a single quote in your string. You can follow the example in `'UNLOAD ( ''select '`.